# MySQL - Use UNION to create a dynamic query that would integrate records from 30 different tables every month

Tags: mysql, union, dynamic-sql

I have datewise data in 30 different tables. The names of the tables are as follows - `wh_available_items.01/06/2022`, `wh_available_items.02/06/2022`, and so on for the rest of the dates of the month of June.

I want to combine all these records in a single report. I can do that using the following query -

```
SELECT '1 June 2022', a.* FROM table1 AS a
UNION 
SELECT '2 June 2022', b.* FROM table2 AS b
UNION
...
SELECT '30 June 2022', a4.* FROM table30 AS a4
```

I wanted to know if there's a way I could write a **dynamic query that would generate a monthly report at the end of every month**. So when a report is required for the month of July, it would integrate datewise tables for that month and create a similar report.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I believe the dynamism part will be for the SQL that will in turn generate the resulting SQL query combining all tables with UNION. Possibly a recursive CTE query can be used for same to generate date-wise table names.

Comment: If there is the possibility that a day is missing I would use a procedure checking what tables exist for the month and year required before generating dynamic code.

Comment: Luckily, that's not a possibility.

Comment: I'd start by fixing the schema so you just have one table called `wh_available_items`, and each row is date stamped. That would make this sort of report trivial.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular that is perhaps the most rational way to approach this. However, I want to see if that can be done using a SQL query.